# How to insert/update larger size of data in the Oracle tables? 

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, clob

I want to insert large size of data that character length is more than 10,000. I used CLOB data type to each column. I can't insert/update that large data it shows following error:

```
ORA-01704: string literal too long
```

My code

```
 insert into table1 value(1,'values>10000');
```

Comment: What application do you use to insert/update data? SQL*Plus, PHP, Java,...? Can you post your code? In [Performing basic string operations on CLOBs](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Oracle/0660__Large-Objects/PerformingbasicstringoperationsonCLOBs.htm) you can view a sample.

Comment: Take a look to previous link. May be a good starting point.

Comment: My code : insert into table1 value(1,'values>10000');

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You'll have to assign the value to a variable & use the variable to insert the data

```
DECLARE
    v_long_text CLOB;
BEGIN
    v_long_text := 'your long string of text';

    INSERT INTO table
    VALUES      (1,
                 v_long_text);
END;
```

---

To make it clear: there are limits set to character strings:

you cannot have a string literal over

- 4000 bytes in SQL
- 32k in PLSQL

If you want to go above this, you'll have to use bind variables.

Comment: Thank sathya but if it's 3,00,000 or greater it again shows error like ORA-06550 PL-sql-00172:string literal too long

Comment: please give some tips to use bind variables

Comment: Search using Google, you'll find plenty of examples http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Oracle/0440__PL-SQL-Statements/UsingMultipleBindVariables.htm http://psoug.org/reference/bindvars.html @ManoharKulanthaivel

Comment: DECLARE
    v_long_text CLOB;
BEGIN
    v_long_text := 'your long string of text';

    update table set col1 =1 col2=:v_long_text where col3='in');
END;it is not working.please give write syntax.

Comment: @ManoharKulanthaivel [search for execute immediate](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/dynamic.htm#CHDGJEGD), if you want to use bind variables. I still don't believe that you'll enter the 32k+ character manually - if you're fetching the lengthy string from a table or XML file, my solution should work fine.

Comment: i get that values from xml than i encrypt it.than i update to the table. but during update it hang. in sql*plus it show string literal too long.your insert statement working fine instead of please give update query.

Comment: update pl/sql execute successfully but not affect the table.i'm using toad for oracle.

Comment: @SathyajithBhat I am the co-maintainer of a tool that generates SQL to do database migrations (FluentMigrator).  My tool can generate 32k+ characters.  What code do you suggest I generate to avoid this problem?  Can I concatenate two `CLOB`s together using `||` to get up to 64k characters, and so on?

Comment: @JohnZabroski if you concatenate them - you'd still run into the issue, wouldn't you as this is a limit on the variable itself. I haven't been on PL/SQL for about half a decade now so I cannot answer that for sure

Comment: @SathyajithBhat FluentMigrator 3.2.8 now supports this workaround transparently to the user of FluentMigrator, so it does indeed work.

Comment: @JohnZabroski awesome to hear that